# Context Manager without Yield

Tags: python, contextmanager

Can I have a context manager which occasionally does not yield, and in which case the code within the with statement are simply not executed?

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def MayNotYield(to_yield):
  if to_yield:
    yield

with MayNotYield(True):  
  print 'This works.'

with MayNotYield(False):  
  print 'This errors.'
```

I could ask the user to wrap the with statement with a try-catch, but that is not preferred. I could also do the following but it is ugly too.

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def AlwaysYields(to_yield):
  if to_yield:
    yield 1
  else:
    yield 2

with AlwaysYields(True) as result:
  if result == 1:
    print 'This works.'
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: My use case is that I put initialization and clean up code in a context manager. The user of the context manager runs their code in the body. My context manager also forks a few processes and only one process is left to the user. All the other processes are to be handled by the library itself.

Comment: @shaoyl85: That still doesn't say why you wouldn't `yield`. It looks like you're trying to combine an `if` statement with a context manager to get around the inability to assign in an `if` statement, not trying to manage resources.

Comment: Could you explain this in the question, and give a less abstract example? It may help clarify whether this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and get you better answers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thank you! I believe my problem can have tons of solutions. My current question is just about whether it is possible to skip the yield. And I think the answer is indeed like what Blckknght said, the "with" statement itself does not have an option to skip the body. It is not the problem of the contextlib.contextmanager. I'm good with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the context manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=context%20manager#with-statement-context-managers) does not give a context manager a way to say "Don't run the `with` block" (except raising an exception in `__enter__`). If you're using a context manager anyway, I think your second approach, which has `__enter__` return a value to signal if the block should be run is the best approach. If you don't need a context manager for some other reason, you could just use a simple `if` statement:

```
if do_stuff:
    # do the stuff
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to just use a regular generator rather than a contextmanager; a plain generator won't have this restriction.  But you'll have to use it with a "for" construct rather than using "with":

```
def MayNotYield(to_yield):
   if to_yield:
      yield

for _ in MayNotYield(True):
   print('This prints.')

for _ in MayNotYield(False):
   print('This does not.')
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the goal of having the conditional within the context manager implementation, there is another possibility in cases where it is possible to extract the the contents of the with-block into its own function. You can pass this callable to the context manager and have the context manager return the passed callable or a dummy do-nothing callable from the context manager depending on the boolean. The with-block will always execute, but the action may or may not be invoked.

```
def do_something():
    print("This works!")

@contextlib.contextmanager
def conditional_on(condition, f):
    if condition:
        # Acquire resources here
        pass
    else:
        # Replace the callable with a do-nothing dummy
        f = lambda x: x
    try:
        yield f
    finally:
        if condition:
            # Release resources here
            pass    

with conditional_on(True, do_something) as f:
    f()  # Prints message

with conditional_on(False, do_something) as f:
    f()  # Does nothing
```

You will need to tailor this solution depending on which, if any, resources the context manager is managing, and on the required signature of of the callable.